# Removing the single quotes after using re.sub() in python

Tags: python, regex

After replacing all word characters in a string with the character '^', using `re.sub("\w", "^" , stringorphrase)` I'm left with :

```
>>> '^^^ ^^ ^^^^'
```

Is there any way to remove the single quotes so it looks cleaner?

```
>>> ^^^ ^^ ^^^^
```

Comment: Can't you also use the same sub method for the single quote?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could also (depending on your use case) remove word characters with `''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())`, where `s` is your string (if you are defining 'word' as 'letters').

Comment: If you do `repr(mystring)`, how many sets of quotes do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `print` statement. The quotes aren't actually part of the string.

Comment: thanks, forgot my main prints the statement, was calling it through the interactive promt.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure it's just not how it's displayed in the interactive prompt or something (and there aren't actually apost's in your string)?

If the `'` is actually part of the string, and is first/last then either:

```
string = string.strip("'")
```

or:

```
string = string[1:-1] # lop ending characters off
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all occurrences of single quotes:

```
mystr = some_string_with_single_quotes
answer = mystr.replace("'", '')
```

To remove single quotes ONLY at the ends of the string:

```
mystr = some_string_with_single_quotes
answer = mystr.strip("'")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the string itself doesnt have single quotes, its after regexing im left with the right replacements, but with single quotes in the beggining and end.

Comment: Then do what Mark Ransom said and `print` the sucker!

Comment: printing the statement worked, thanks! was calling the function in the interactive promt, oops lool.